# Get user count from one row - Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

```
Create table test4(
    id number,
    user_1 varchar2(100),
    user_2 varchar2(100),
    user_3 varchar2(100),
    user_4 varchar2(100)
    )
    
    Insert into test4(id,user_1,user_2,user_3,user_4) values (1,'MARK','CLARC','KING','KING');
```

How get results as:

```
user        total
---------------------
MARC        1
CLARC       1
KING        2
```

Comment: Is this homework? you are looking for GROUP BY and COUNT.

Comment: I'd consider one user column instead, and several rows.

Comment: As it is now, you'll have to UNION ALL the user columns first, then GROUP BY the result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `UNPIVOT` (which only requires a single table-scan):

```sql
SELECT name,
       COUNT(*)
FROM   test4
UNPIVOT (name FOR key IN (user_1, user_2, user_3, user_4))
GROUP BY name
```

Outputs:

> | NAME | COUNT(*) |
> | --- | --- |
> | KING | 2 |
> | MARK | 1 |
> | CLARC | 1 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=797af33bdb55dbd424997b39e0aadac0)*

Answer (score 2):

something like this maybe :

```sql
select user, count(*) from (
    select user_1 as user from test4 union all 
    select user_2 as user from test4 union all 
    select user_3 as user from test4 union all 
    select user_4 as user from test4
) t 
group by user
```